# can I dynamically set the ID and view name?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

```
    <core:mvc.XMLView id="{path:' AssignmentModel>/AssignmentType' ,formatter:'.getViewName'}" 
            viewName="{path:' AssignmentModel>/AssignmentType' ,formatter:'.getViewName'}" 
            height="100%" visible="true"/>
```

I want view to be loaded based on assignemnt type. 
I tried to dynamically load the view from controller, based on type. 
but that itsnt working as expected.

Comment: Why not use the Routing mechanism, and navigate to the view based on the assignment type?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a View in an XMLView it will be created once. Even if your binding was working it would be OneTime, meaning it is only resolved once, which is obviously not what you are looking for.

You either have to use [Routing](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/3d18f20bd2294228acb6910d8e8a5fb5.html) as qualiture already mentioned or load your content dynamically from your controller and manually insert it in your view hierarchy. You could still use a PropertyBinding to observe property changes like this:

```
 var binding = new sap.ui.model.PropertyBinding("AssignmentModel", "/AssignmentType");
 binding.attachChange(function() {
   var sViewName = this.getViewName(this.getModel("AssignmentModel").getProperty("/AssignmentType");
   var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
     id: sViewName
     viewName: sViewName
   });
   // pack your view whereever you want, clean the old view before
   this.getView().addContent(oView);
 }, this)
```

You might need to use `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataPropertyBinding` depending on the model you are using.

Code above is untested but it 'should' work.

GL
Chris